# Entity Framework 6 DbGeography.Distance() incorrect and inconsistent

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, geospatial

I'm getting some seriously baffling behavior using DbGeography class and trying to find the distance between 2 points. I'm aware the format for these coordinates is WKT (long, lat), however I'm still getting incorrect values, and they're not even consistent.

Check out these 2 screenshots on break statements, the second taken one iteration after in the loop.

I'm getting all these weird negative numbers for the distance...But even more so, it seems to calculate them inconsistently. Look at the watch expression for

```
coordinateInMemory.Distance(userCoordinateInMemory)
```

It gives -3.96..... meanwhile `distanceInMemory`, (which is set using the same line of code!) has value 10036....

In the second screenshot theyre all negative numbers, even though the 2 points in the watch are valid longitude, latitude points in new york

What in the heck is going on?

[image]
[image]

```
    public DbGeography CreatePoint(double longitude, double latitude)
    {
        var text = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat,
                    "POINT({0} {1})", longitude, latitude);
        // 4326 is most common coordinate system used by GPS/Maps
        return DbGeography.PointFromText(text, 4326);
    }
```

Comment: sorry if the missing code makes it alittle unclear   newYorkers array is a materialized entity query and currentUser is an attached entity user

Comment: Firstly, the distance should definitely be 10036.482... Other than, this is extremely odd behaviour.  What version of EF6 are you using?  I assume there are no other threads that are altering the data?